# Firestore access?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Has anyone got into this problem as well?

Firefox:

The operation failed because the stored database is a higher version than the version requested.

Chrome:

Firestore (4.5.0) 2018-08-03T11:00:22.861Z: INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (3).

Comment: I think it is coming from `indexedDb` that browsers use to cache data. ex: when you use firestore for local and production in the same browser. Clear the browser cache and try again

Comment: that was it, thank you @OmurbekKadyrbekov :)

Comment: *firebaser here* This sounds like it could be a bug. If you can reproduce getting this error, please [file a bug report against our JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues).

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov 's comment could be an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is coming from indexedDb that browsers use to cache data. ex: when you use firestore for local and production in the same browser. Clear the browser cache and try again